# Retrieving div attribute within a lightning input element

Tags: lightning-web-components, javascript, html

I'm retrieving all `lightning-input` fields on my page using `querySelectorAll('lightning-input')` and this is what is being returned :

(There is more than 1 input field on my page and this is a simplified example)

```
<lightning-input class="" ..>
 <div>
   <input name="field"/>
 </div>
</lightning-input>
```

My thought process was to grab the children of the `lightning-input` which in this case should 1 child (div). Once I get to the div, I would get it's children (only 1 - input field) so I'd be where I want to be and get the name attribute.

```
const allInputs = Array.from(this.template.querySelectorAll("lightning-input");
const result = Array.map((element) => {
   console.log(element.children.length) //returns 0, shouldn't it be 1?
)};
```

I want to get the value of the `name` attribute on the `input` tag which lies within a `div` tag. How can I do this?

Comment: why are you using querySelectorAll for 1 element?

Comment: This is a simplified example. In reality, my page contains many `lightning-input` fields

Comment: i'm not asking about the lighting input, but the method for querying dom elements

Comment: Yeah, I know. My page contains multiple of `lightning-input` fields which is why I'm using the `querySelectorAll` function

Comment: in that case, i'm not sure what your quesiton is, since querySelectorAll returns an array of DOM elements, what have yout tried exactly to get the name attribute

Comment: Well, I've tried to get the children of the `lightning-input` thinking that I can access the 3rd child which is the div and get it's children to get the name attribute off the input tag. Not sure why but the children value keeps returning 0

Comment: how have you tried? can you please add the code to your post?

Comment: You can't get into a component's internal components. I'm not sure why you'd want to, either, since the `name` attribute is directly exposed to the parent: `this.template.querySelector('lightning-input').name`

Comment: I'm going suggest that you read about the [X-Y Problem](https://xyproblem.info/). You're asking about a Y, but you need to ask about the X problem instead.

Answer (score 1):

`lightning-input` is an `LWC` - which means its internal markup is hidden from you.

You will be able to retrieve all the various inputs in your `querySelectorAll` call, but you won't be able to get anything internal.

Of course, you'll be able to access anything that is exposed via the `API` on any of the components, but that's all.